# What is a UX Corner case?

Tags: usability-testing

What is a UX Corner case? What difference is it compared with an edge case? How can we identify them?
Would you be kind enough to please help understand this concept from a engineer perspective.

Answer (score 6):

An edge case is when one parameter causes rare issues. For example leap days, when you've hardcoded 365 days.

A corner case is when multiple parameters or edge cases meet. That's all.
For example when your interface breaks only on right-to-left sites, on leap days, and if you have more than 12 tasks in your agenda.

What's important to understand that a corner case is exponentially harder to figure out, based on the amount of factors involved. But I don't think anyone will be confused when you call both of them an edge-case.